# Google protobuf mergeFrom merges duplicate values

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am making few parallel calls which all returns same protobuf GeneratedMessage (with some values different). In the next step I am building a new GeneratedMessage instance and calling mergeFrom with all the parallel outputs one by one.

```
// For example, consider a GeneratedMessage named Store
Store s1 = ... some process which return Store
Store s2 = ... some process which return Store
Store s3 = ... some process which return Store
Store.Builder result = Store.newBuilder();
result.mergeFrom(s1);
result.mergeFrom(s2);
result.mergeFrom(s3);
```

Consider Store has repeated field and all outputs return same list of values for that field. Consider List as one field in Store and they all return same 3 values for this field. When I merge all these outputs, final result has duplicate values (Total 9 values, 3 from each) for that field.

Is there anyway I can merge and keep unique values?